# Wifi automatically disconnects in edubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: wireless, hp, realtek-wireless, edubuntu

Wifi signal is very low in ubuntu and if i connect it will automatically disconnects after a few minutes please help me to solve this problem.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep 0280 -A3 –
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c] 
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please specify your WiFi model.

Comment: Please update your question to include the output of the command `lspci -knn | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: Close Voters:  What about this particular question indicates to you that the wireless card is an rtl8723?

Comment: 0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

Comment: How it is a duplicate my kernel driver in use is rtl8723be and in the duplicate you given kernel driver in use is rtl8723ae

Comment: I have reopened the question but please [edit] and give us more information. What version of Ubuntu is this? You need to tell us the actual version in your question, don't just tag with "Edubuntu".  Also show us the output of running `dmesg | tail -n40` just after it disconnects so we can see what errors are printed.